# Blocking code in custom message box in VB6

Tags: vb6, messagebox

In my vb6 project, I created my own msgbox using a form, due to difficulties in changing
the font/language of in-built msgbox. A search with google gave the idea of own msg-
box rather than trying msgbox of VB. Now the problem is : - when the user exits the
program, 3 options are given: to close, to  restart and to cancel exit. The user need not
again go through the process of giving  password etc in restart option. If I give cancel =
true in the QueryUnload  event, then 2nd option does not work, 3rd option works. If
cancel = true is not given, 2nd option works, but 3rd option does not. It appears that
the main form does not get unloaded if cancel = true.  Unless & until the main form
unloads,  the program will not work with the fresh data to be given by the user in the
initial Form. Since the code after "msgbox.show" depends on options, it is not possible
to write that code in the same sub, not even in the same form code. Is there any way
to stop the subsequent code after "msgbox.show" and continue the same after getting
option? (like in the in-built msgbox of VB.) I am not an expert in VB, so please correct
if I made some mistake; also help with advice/suggestions.

EDIT:- [Extended explanation]

The 3 forms in my project:

1. Initial form for password, data etc. This is input Form for user.
2. Main Form. This Form shows the results after process of input.
3. frmMsgBox. This is a custom msgbox created using a form.

Main Form code portion. Code for closing the program:

```
 Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel as.......)
   cancel = True
   frmMsgBox.Label1.caption = Do you wish to 1.Exit  2.Restart
   3.Cancel the exit?
   frmMsgBox.Show
 End sub
```

(The above msgbox is almost like an in-built msgbox in VB with
`vbYesNoCancel` buttons) The message is in regional language,
which was the main reason forced me to use my own msgbox.

After MsgBox appears, the user selects one of the above options
using 3 commandButtons placed in that Form. The code after
clicking these buttons is written in the code portion of frmMsgBox:

```
  Command1_Click  'This is for Exit from the Program.
  All Forms.unload, All forms set to nothing, end.

  Command2_click  'This is for restarting the Program.
  Unload Main Form, set to nothing
  Load Initial Form
  Initial Fom.show
  frmMsgBox.Hide

  Command3_Click  'This is for cancelling the exit request. 
  Main Form.Show
  frmMsgBox.Hide
```

With the above code, I have no problem with options 1 & 3,
i.e; to exit from the program or to start. The frmMsgBox hides,
the initial form shows -  these are OK, but the main form does
not unload nor it is removed from memory. Because of this,
whatever new data is given by the user in the initial form now
is not being processed, the main form is struck with the old results.

If cancel = true is removed from the code above, Options 1 & 2
are OK, but option 3 does not work. Then the Main Form loses
all its results (all labels, texts etc in that Form turn blank.)

Comment: Probably better for you to paste your **real code** so that people can see what really happens. This pseudocode may not be very helpful.

Comment: @StayOnTarget Thank you for the response. But I am afraid this is the entirety of my code. Outside custom form names, this is all of it.

Comment: Its not valid syntax, so at best its partial / stripped down code

Comment: You should read about modal forms. Your custom MsgBox form should be displayed as a modal form and it should **not** have any code controlling the state of the application. Instead it should return only which button the uses clicked and nothing more. I can give you a complete example of a custom MsgBox once you are aware of how modal forms work and how to handle your 3 cases in your Main form's QueryUnload event instead.